# Why isn't :checked working for my radio buttons?

Tags: html, css, angular, radio-button, checked

So I created a quiz form and wanted to change the style of the radio buttons, which I did, but now you can't tell when an option has been selected, but the answers are still being recorded. How can I make the selected option change background color?

This is the HTML for one question:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label
              >{{ quizQuestions[0] }}
              <div class="radio"  *ngFor="let flavor of answerSetOne">
                <label id="radio">
                  <input  
                  checked 
                  type="radio" 
                  name="flavor" 
                  class="btn-check" 
                  ngModel [value]="flavor.num" 
                  required/>
                  {{ flavor.name | titlecase}}
                </label>
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>
```

And the CSS that I believe should work:

````
      opacity: 0;
      position: fixed;
      width: 0;
    }

    .radio label {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: rgb(248, 174, 89);
      padding: 10px 20px;
      font-size: 14px;
      border-radius: 4px;
  }

  .radio input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    background-color:rgb(114, 31, 6);
}
```an
````

Answer (score 0):

In your css you need to quote your type:

```
.radio input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
```

Comment: @AllisonBarnett If you try setting this line to just `.radio input:checked {` does it work?

Comment: No that doesn't work either :/ I'm worried it's because of my nested labels maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```css
      opacity: 0;
      position: fixed;
      width: 0;
    }

    .radio label {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: rgb(248, 174, 89);
      padding: 10px 20px;
      font-size: 14px;
      border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .radio input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color:rgb(114, 31, 6);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
            <label
              >{{ quizQuestions[0] }}
              <div class="radio"  *ngFor="let flavor of answerSetOne">
                <label id="radio">
                  <input  
                  checked 
                  type="radio" 
                  name="flavor" 
                  class="btn-check" 
                  ngModel [value]="flavor.num" 
                  required/>
        {{ flavor.name | titlecase}}
                </label>
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>
```